# Mongoose/ MongoDB Database Design

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I always have a certain fixed structure in my model (GroupName) and a dynamic part of 1-x (Members).

```
Group1 
  GroupName
  Member 1
  Member 2
Group2
  GroupName
  Member 1
Group3
  GroupName
  Member 1
  Member 2
  Member 3
```

Is it better to use two tables and connect them later via ids like this:

```
Groups:
  Group1
    GroupName
    GroupId
  Group2
    GroupName
    GroupId

Members:
  Member 1
   GroupId 
  Member 2
   GroupId
```

or to use `Schema.Types.Mixed`(or anything else)? And how to do it in the second way?

I will always use them in combination later. From a gut feeling I would choose the first method:
http://blog.mongolab.com/2013/04/thinking-about-arrays-in-mongodb/

EDIT: 
But even on the second method I have the issue, that one member can belong to multiple groups and I don't want to store him twice. The groups are unique and do only exist once.

*But I'm new to MongoDb so I want to learn what's the best option and why.*

EDIT II:
I have choosen two divide it into two docs. Is this implementation of the Schemas than correct like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// define the schema for group model
var groupSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  href: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true
  },
  title: String,
  members: [id: Schema.Types.ObjectId, name: String]
});

// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('group', groupSchema);
```

&&

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// define the schema for member model
var memberSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  id: {
    type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  amount: String,
  name: String
});


// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('member', memberSchema);
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an excellent [post](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) on the MongoDB blog which tells us about the various ways a schema can be designed based on the model relationships.

I believe the best schema for you would be to make use of embedded arrays with the member IDs.

```
//Group
{
    _id: '1234',
    name: 'some group',
    members : [
         'abcd',
         'efgh'
        ]
}
```

**EDIT**

There is a correction needed in the schema:

```
// define the schema for group model
var groupSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  href: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true
  },
  title: String,
  members: [{id: Schema.Types.ObjectId, name: String}] //Needs to be enclosed with braces
});

// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('group', groupSchema);
```

Comment: Yes after reading that post this sounds also the best. I have a one-n relationship but I want to access the members also solo. Actually the members are pretty static and rarely updated. So I will choose the denormalized way for the members name. Am I right that in my schema for mongoose I define the members as array?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. You can also provide a type for the array, like [String] or [SomeSchema]

Comment: Would be great if you can check EDIT II. Thanks for helping me. I always feel a little bit lost when starting s.th new.

Comment: @AndiGiga We've all been there. Check the edit to my answer. There was a small error in the Schema.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your documents contains and if members are a growing array - for example `Group1` can have 1-n `members` in any given moment . if this is the case you should go with option 2: try something like:

```
{gId: 1, mId: 5}
```

That is a design best suited for `Social graph`. Your `Group documents` will have a fixed size which is good for memory and you can easily get all the members of a group (just don't forget to index `gId` and `mId`)

If for each group there is a fixed number of members (or not growing and shrinking to much) then go with option 1

There is a great post by mongoDb team (and also src code) that talks about design.

[Socialite](http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/socialite-open-source-status-feed-part-2-managing-social-graph)